# Is it possible to change Yeoman's directory structure?

Tags: yeoman

I like Yeoman's features like the Package Manager (Bower), Livereload integration, Compass, etc.

Therefor, I'd like to use it to handle my public website. However, instead of using the "app" folder, I would like to put everything at the root.

I've changed the references in the grunt configuration file but still get errors when installing new package and building.

Is it possible to change the project structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as easy as it could be at the moment, but we're working on making it easily customizable.

Though I don't think you would need to. You develop in the /app folder and deploy the contents of the built /dist folder. That way it's still in the root on your server.

Comment: Yes, at least for another week or two.

Comment: How about now? Still the case? If not, can you please link to the doc describing how to customize.