# Directory Structure for Yeoman apps

Tags: yeoman

With the lastest yeoman update, 1.0, are we able to change the way a directory structure is created? ex...If I want to create my files within the root directory instead of the '/app' folder, is this possible? Also, if we want to name our assets folders 'css', 'js' or 'img', can this be achieved?

I make reference to this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691803/is-it-possible-to-change-yeomans-directory-structure) for an update.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, everything is now contained inside the Gruntfile.js. You are free to change whatever you want. We have defined a couple of [shortcuts](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/1e31faa71f2c73e9017a242fee3a080087843ca7/app/templates/Gruntfile.js#L11-L15) at the top for quickly changing the `app` and `dist` directory.

Check out the [grunt docs](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile) on how to go about doing that.